# python greenlet SSL EOF error

Tags: python

I keep getting the following error but i have no idea how to `try..except` it or handle it.  Any ideas?

The error happens when i load test the server or if I send a request on port 443 that is not SSL, such as `http://server:443/call`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 102, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 383, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    return self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
<Greenlet at 0x7f74b804eb90: <bound method WSGIServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of <WSGIServer at 0x7f74b9d16810 fileno=7 address=0.0.0.0:443>>(<socket at 0x7f74b2442590 fileno=198 sock=46.101.4, ('54.198.34.85', 26771))> failed with SSLError
```

The code on a basic level is as follows

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

try:
    class HttpsHandler:
      def application(self, env, start_response):
          start_response("200 OK", "Content-Length: 0")
          return []

    WSGIServer(
        ('', 443),
        application=HttpsHandler().application,
        keyfile=cfg.ssl_keyfile,
        certfile=cfg.ssl_crtfile,
        ca_certs=cfg.ssl_cacerts,
        log=open('logs/access.log', 'a')
    ).serve_forever()
except Exception, e:
    print e
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    pass
```

Comment: Answer to this is I wrote my own web server and used nginx to terminate SSL and proxy back to uwsgi. If any one wants to see my server code : https://github.com/ccsalway/pywebserver